# Most standard way to select a function name depending on platform?

Tags: c, portability, popen

I am currently using the `popen` function in code that is compiled by two compilers: MS Visual Studio and gcc (on linux). I might want to add gcc (on MinGW) later.

The function is called `popen` for gcc, but `_popen` for MSVS, so i added the following to my source code:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define popen _popen
#define pclose _pclose
#endif
```

This works, but i would like to understand whether there exists a standard solution for such problems (i recall a similar case with `stricmp`/`strcasecmp`). Specifically, i would like to understand the following:

1. Is `_MSC_VER` the right flag to depend on? I chose it because i have the impression that linux environment is "more standard".
2. If i put these `#define`'s in some header file, is it important whether i `#include` it before or after `stdio.h` (for the case of `popen`)?
3. If `_popen` is defined as a macro itself, is there a chance my `#define` will fail? Should i use a "new" token like `my_popen` instead, for that reason or another?
4. Did someone already do this job for me and made a good "portability header" file that i can use?
5. Anything else i should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it is fine (with the `#ifdef` etc) but the macro that you test isn't. `popen` is something that depends on your operating system and not your compiler.

I'd go for something like

```
#if defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) && (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 2)
/* system has popen as expected */
#elif defined(YOUR_MACRO_TO DETECT_YOUR_OS)
# define popen _popen
# define pclose _pclose
#elif defined(YOUR_MACRO_TO DETECT_ANOTHER_ONE)
# define popen _pOpenOrSo
# define pclose _pclos
#else
# error "no popen, we don't know what to do"
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Better to check for a windows-specific define (_WIN32 perhaps) because mingw won't have it either. popen() is standardised (it's a [part of the Single UNIX® Specification v2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/popen.html))
2. No; so long as the macro is defined before its first use it does not matter if _popen() is not defined until later.
3. No; what you have is fine even if _popen is a macro.
4. It's been done many times but I don't know of a freely-licensed version you can use.

Answer (score 1):

1. `_MSC_VER` is the correct macro for detecting the MSVC compiler. You can use `__GNUC__` for GCC.
2. If you are going to use `popen` as your macro ID, I suggest you `#include` it after, because of 3.
3. If you `#include` it after `stdio.h`, it should work AFAIK, but better safe than sorry, no? Call it `portable_popen` or something.
4. Many projects (including some of mine) have a portability header, but it's usually better to roll your own. I'm a fan of doing things yourself if you have the time. Thus you know the details of your code (easier to debug if things go wrong), and you get code that is tailored to your needs.
5. Not that I know of. I do stuff like this all the time, without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ending up with cluttered files containing `#ifdef`..`#else`..`#endif` blocks, I'd prefer a version using different files for different platforms:

- put the OS dependent definitions in one file per platform and `#define` a macro `my_popen`
- `#include` this file in your platform-agnostic code
- never call the OS functions directly, but the `#define` that you created (i.e. `my_popen`)
- depending on your OS, use different headers for compilation (e.g. `config/windows/mydefines.h` on windows and `config/linux/mydefines.h` on linux, so set the include path appropriate and always `#include "mydefines.h"`)

That's a much cleaner approach than having the OS decision in the source itself.

If the methods you're calling behave different between windows and linux, decide which one shall be the behavior you're using (i.e. either **always** windows behavior or **always** linux behavior) and then create wrapper methods to achieve this. For that, you'll also need not only two `mydefines.h` files but also to `myfunctions.c` files that reside in the `config/OSTYPE` directories.

Doing it that way, you also get advantages when it comes to diff the linux and the windows version: you could simply diff two files while doing a diff on the linux and windows blocks of the **same** file could be difficult.